# Finding out if location services are enabled is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I have an app which uses the device location. If they allow the location, I want to run my method `getDataFromJson` and run my app as normal. If they deny it, or have denied it before, I wish to show them a view explaining they need to go to settings and allow it.

I have a lot of code, but it doesn't work at the moment. Can anyone help explain where the problem is?

Many thanks!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == YES) {
        //are enabled, run the JSON request
        [self getDataFromJson];
    } else {
        //is not enabled, so set it up
        NSLog(@"no");
        [locationManager location];
    };

}

-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) getLocation{

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];
    return coordinate;

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
        //location denied, handle accordingly
        locationFailView.hidden = NO;
        mainView.hidden = YES;
    }
    else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        //hooray! begin tracking
        [self getDataFromJson];
    }
}

//class to convert JSON to NSData
- (IBAction)getDataFromJson {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [self getLocation];
    NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.latitude];
    NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.longitude];
    ...
}
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what specifically do you mean?

Comment: Can you include the text of the crash?

Comment: You need to point out what code is crashing and what the full error is.

Comment: Sorry, bad question. The log prints "no" where you can see above, but no location dialogue shows and nothing runs further...

Comment: Why do you compare `[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]` to `YES`? The return value is an enum with several possible values. Most likely you should be getting a compiler warning. Don't ignore warnings.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, that was the problem, but there was no compiler warning and I would not have ignored one if there was...

Answer (score 3):

```
+ (CLAuthorizationStatus)authorizationStatus
```

> Return Value A value indicating whether the application is authorized
>   to use location services.
>
> Discussion The authorization status of a given application is managed
>   by the system and determined by several factors. Applications must be
>   explicitly authorized to use location services by the user and
>   location services must themselves currently be enabled for the system.
>   This authorization takes place automatically when your application
>   first attempts to use location services.

```
+ (BOOL)locationServicesEnabled
```

> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether location services are
>   enabled on the device.

You may check this two state: locationServicesEnabled and authorizationStatus then decide which method should use.

AuthorizationStatus should check with states:

```
typedef enum {
   kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined = 0,
   kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted,
   kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied,
   kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized
} CLAuthorizationStatus;
```

but you check equal with bool value in viewDidLoad method.

Comment: -(BOOL)locationServicesEnabled is Deprecated in iOS 4.0. Use the -(CLAuthorizationStatus)locationServicesEnabled class method instead.